# CSS transition doesn't work backwards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have I have a standard opacity animation, but it doesn't work in reverse order. Here is JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zumv703f/13/). If I understood the documentation correctly it should work automatically. I am beginner in js so is this a problem in javascript? Or CSS animation is wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="bg_layer" class="bg_layer"></div>
<div id="clicker" class="grey"></div>
<div id="galery" class="galery" ></div>
```

JS:

```
   clicker.onclick = function() {  
document.getElementById("bg_layer").style.opacity = "0.7";
bg_layer.style.visibility = 'visible';
galery.style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById("galery").style.opacity = "1";};
   bg_layer.onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("bg_layer").style.opacity = "0";
bg_layer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
galery.style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("galery").style.opacity = "0";
}
```

CSS:

```
html{
min-height:100%;
position:relative;}

body {background-image: url(img/wall.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 100%;
}

 .grey {
    float: right;
  background: #d6d6d6;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.bg_layer {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 98;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #000000;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.galery {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 170px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #ff0000;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: you are also playing with visibility so this one need transition also ... simply change `opacity` to `all`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not recommended to use `all` as a simple fix, instead add the one's to target, e.g. `transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, visibility 0.5s ease-in-out;`, and the reason is, if one later add some other value, e.g. a `width`, in the wrong way it will animate that too, and that might be difficult to debug.

Comment: @LGSon yes I agree ;) but it was a quick comment to highlight his issue then of course we should do things correctly and more accurate

Comment: Thank you guys i totally forgot about visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the transition property from `transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out` to  `transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out` so any style properties being changed will start the transition.

```js
clicker.onclick = function() {  
    document.getElementById("bg_layer").style.opacity = "0.7";
    bg_layer.style.visibility = 'visible';
    galery.style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("galery").style.opacity = "1";};

bg_layer.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("bg_layer").style.opacity = "0";
    bg_layer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    galery.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("galery").style.opacity = "0";
}
```

```css
html{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {background-image: url(img/wall.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 100%;
}


 .grey {
    float: right;
  background: #d6d6d6;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;

}



.bg_layer {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 98;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #000000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.galery {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 170px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #ff0000;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg_layer" class="bg_layer"></div>
<div id="clicker" class="grey"></div>

<div id="galery" class="galery" ></div>
```

Comment: Not recommended to use `all` as a simple fix, instead add the one's to target, e.g. `transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, visibility 0.5s ease-in-out;`, and the reason is, if one later add some other value, e.g. a `width`, in the wrong way it will animate that too, and that might be difficult to debug.

Comment: @Asons do you have any feedback on how to do this without using `all`?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo Asons mentioned `transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, visibility 0.5s ease-in-out;` as one possible alternative.

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo -- As commented, one way is in my comment, were one simply add a list of properties for the transition.